# Quicksort without the final merge Python

Tags: python, quicksort

I am new to coding and trying to implement quicksort in python. The following is the code but the output is not correct. Where am I going wrong?
Choosing pivot as the first element and without having to merge.

```
def quicksort(A):
if len(A) > 1:
    p = A[0]
    i = 0

    for j in A[1:]:
        if j < p:
            A[i] , j = j , A[i]
            i = i+1

        A[0] , A[i] = A[i] , A[0]

    left = A[:i]
    right = A[i+1:]
    left = quicksort(left)
    right = quicksort(right)

    return A
else:
    return A
```

After the changes, the code is

```
def quicksort(A, left = None, right =None):
if left is None:
    left = 0
if right is None:
    right = len(A)
p =A[left]

i = left +1
for j in A[left+1:right]:
    if A[j] < p:
        A[i] , A[j] = A[j], A[i]
        i = i + 1
A[left] , A[i-1] = A[i-1], A[left]
quicksort(A[:i])
quicksort(A[i+1:])

return A
```

I am getting a error, list index out of range.

Comment: You should be returning `left + right`, not `A`, and this swap: `A[i], j = j, A[i]` is wrong. You need to swap the *index of `A` containing `j`* with `A[i]`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing these out. But I am trying to implement inplace swap in quicksort. I got a algorithm from [link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort). It is also returning a wrong result.

Comment: If you your algorithm to be in-place, you need to follow the advice of @gnibbler, and just pass the indices of `A` to operate on, rather than using list slicing. It would only take minimal changes to what you have now.

Comment: @dano , as per the advice I edited the post with the new code, where is it going wrong?

Comment: When you use `for j in A[left+1:right]:`, `j` is the *value* in `A` for each item inside in the `A[left+1:right]` slice. But you're treating it like its an index: `if A[j] < p`. You want to say `for j in range(left+1, right):`. You're also still using list slicing: e.g. `quicksort(A[:i])`, which creates a copy of `A`. That means 1) you're not sorting in-place 2) You're not actually changing `A` when you start making recursive calls, you're changing copies of `A`, which never get bubbled back up the stack. You need to call `quicksort(A, left, i)` and `quicksort(A, i+1, right)` instead.

Comment: I made the two changes, the shell is printing some error infinitely and then crashing.

Comment: You don't have a base case. Add `if left >= right: return` after the `if right is None: right = len(A)` check.

Comment: The error is maximum recursion depth exceeded at the line `quicksort(A, left, i)`. I have added the base case.

Comment: You need to call `quicksort(A, left, i-1)` instead of `quicksort(A, left, i)`.

Comment: I tried that. Not working. I will go through the code again and get back on this later. Thanks a lot for helping me out. I never knew so much could be learnt in writing a program.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I have a working version that just makes the changes I've suggested. Post your actual code again if you can't figure it out.

Comment: The error is appearing no more. But the results are almost correct, expect for the middle two elements interchanged.

Comment: I got the mistake. The second recursive call is supposed to be `quicksort(A, i ,right)` instead of `quicksort(A, i+1 , right)`. It is working perfectly now. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are making *copies* of slices of A

```
left = A[:i]
right = A[i+1:]
```

Anything you do to the copy won't affect A

To modify `A` inplace, you should pass it as well as left and right indices as parameters

```
def quicksort(A, left=None, right=None):
    if left is None:
        left = 0
    if right is None
        right = len(A)
    ...
```

Now remembering that `left` and `right` are indices here (not lists as in your code). Modify the rest of your function to make changes to `A` directly

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I tried to implement the inplace code from [link]http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort using the given algorithm. It is giving a wrong result. And can you elaborate on usage of None placeholder above.

Comment: I mean why can't we initialize left and right with a value directly?

Comment: @user3332615 The idea is a user could just call `quicksort(mylist)`, rather than `quicksort(mylist, 0, len(mylist))`.